# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar una contraseña de forma que quede "******"?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en C# con Visual Studio 2017 (más específicamente, en un WPF) y necesito ocultar el contenido de un `TextBox` que es una contraseña. Sé que en Forms se usaba el `PasswordChar`, pero en WPF no existe, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: NVM descubri que algo que se llama PasswordBox jaja

Comment: Es correcto compañero, tal y como lo descubriste, te comparto un tutorial del mismo para mayor información: https://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html Espero te sea de gran ayuda Saludos cordiales,

Comment: Hay un campo denominado PasswordBox, quizas puedas hacer uso de ese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seleccionas el `TextBox` y te vas a la vista de propiedades, existe una propiedad llamada `PasswordChar` que por lo regular esta en blanco; ahí le pones el * y listo:

[image: cambiar el valor de passwordchar por asteriscos]

De ahora en adelante, todo lo que escribas ahí se verá así '*****'.

[image: demo de textbox con asteriscos en lugar de letras]

Comment: Pero eso es de Windows Forms, y el op busca para wpf

Comment: No leí bien esa parte, pero en wpf existen los PasswordBox, espero aun le sirva...